# Создание одного битмапа из нескольких на канвасе

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Имеется 2 битмапа, нужно создать новый с размерами width и height, наложив битмапы друг на друга, и отрисовать его на канвасе. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй сделать так:

```
public static Bitmap overlayBitmapToCenter(Bitmap bitmap1, Bitmap bitmap2) {
    int bitmap1Width = bitmap1.getWidth();
    int bitmap1Height = bitmap1.getHeight();
    int bitmap2Width = bitmap2.getWidth();
    int bitmap2Height = bitmap2.getHeight();

    float marginLeft = (float) (bitmap1Width * 0.5 - bitmap2Width * 0.5);
    float marginTop = (float) (bitmap1Height * 0.5 - bitmap2Height * 0.5);

    Bitmap overlayBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap1Width,  
        bitmap1Height, bitmap1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlayBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap1, new Matrix(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap2, marginLeft, marginTop, null);
    return overlayBitmap;
}
```

Идея такая: ассоциировать `bitmap` и `canvas`, чтобы использовать все методы `canvas` для `bitmap`.
Это работает для `bitmap` со свойством `transparency` (прозрачность).